# Use the definition of a limit to prove this limit

Tags: limits

Use the definition of a limit to show that $\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1} \to \frac{4}{5}$ as $x\to 2$.

I am having trouble isolating the $(x-2)$ from the fraction to use as a delta please help!

Comment: Did you, at any moment, try to compute $$\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1} - \frac{4}{5}\ ?$$ If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1}-\frac45\right|=\left|\frac{15x-10-4x^2-4}{5(x^2+1)}\right|=\left|\frac{4x^2-15x+14}{5(x^2+1)}\right|=\frac{\left|4(x-2)\left(x-\frac74\right)\right|}{5(x^2+1)}=$$
(taking $\,x\,$ very close to $\,2\,$, say $\,x\in\left(2-0.001,\,2+0.001\right)\,$ , we can assure that $\,x-\frac74>0\,$ , so)

$$=\frac{4x-7}{5(x^2+1)}|x-2|\;\;\color{red}{(**)}$$

and now we can estimmate, for $\;x\;$ as above (no need to be specially gentle or subtle with this...):

$$\frac{4x-7}{5(x^2+1)}<\frac2{5\cdot(1+1)}=\frac1{5}\;\;\color{blue}{(*)}$$

so given *any* $\epsilon>0\;$ we can choose $\;\delta=5\epsilon\;$ , and then:

$$\color{green}{(*)}\;\;|x-2|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1}-\frac45\right|\stackrel{\color{red}{(**)}}=\frac{4x-7}{5(x^2+1)}|x-2|\stackrel{\color{green}{(*)+\color{blue}{(*)}}}<\frac15\cdot5\epsilon=\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)\to\frac45$ as $x\to2$ means by definition that for all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is $\delta\gt 0$ such that $|x-2|\lt\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-\frac 45|\lt \epsilon$.

If $f(x)=\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1}$ then given $\epsilon\gt 0$ we calculate
$$\left|\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1}-\frac45\right|=\left|\frac{4x^2-15x+14}{5(x^2+1)}\right|=\left|\frac{(4x-7)(x-2)}{5(x^2+1)}\right|$$ Since 
$$\frac{4x-7}{5(x^2+1)}\lt1$$
which is clear because it is equivalent to $$ 5x^2-4x+12\gt0$$ we can choose $\delta=\epsilon$ so we have $$|x-2|\lt\delta (=\epsilon)\Rightarrow\left|\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1}-\frac45\right|\lt \epsilon$$
This means by definition of limit that $f(x)=\frac{3x-2}{x^2+1}$ tends to $\frac 45$ as $x\to 2$

Answer (score -1):

You can simply set x=2 and solve the equation. You can do this because the equation is defined at x=2. If it were not then you would have to determine what value the function is approaching (usually infinity or zero, but can be anything).

Comment: OP needs to *show* that the limit is $4/5$ from the definition though. Definitely we can just *plug in* the number and be done, but we didn't show that the definition of a limit gave us this information.